# Laravel 8 seeding property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance

Tags: php, laravel

I am rebuilding an old project for a client and moving it to Laravel 8.  I've created all the models and converted all the data from the current project into json so I can migrate the data as seeder data.

I have a `Usercar` model that has a `belongsTo` relationship with the `Car` and the `User` models. I need to re-create the relationships during the seeding process by comparing and matching the old id values in order to create the new records and relationships.  All my seeders run successfully until I get to the **`**UsercarSeeder**`**, then I get a `property [id] does not exist on the Eloquent builder instance` error. I know I am missing something really simple.  Thanks.

**database/data/cars.json**

```
[
    {
        "old_car_id": 31,
        "start_year": 1955,
        "end_year": 1958,
        "model": "356  Carrera 1500 GS Coupe",
        "horse_power": 110,
...
```

**database/data/users.json**

```
[
    {
        "old_user_id": "4be7c3a7-d626-456a-83be-5d303bf90d02",
        "first_name": "Charles",
        "last_name": "Smith",
...
```

**database/data/user-cars.json**

```
[
    {
        "old_user_id": "4be7c3a7-d626-456a-83be-5d303bf90d02",
        "old_car_id": 227,
        "car_color": "Gray",
        "year": 2015,
        "tire_points": 140,
...
```

**database/seeders/UsercarSeeder.php**

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use App\Models\User;
use App\Models\Car;
use App\Models\Usercar;
use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;
use Illuminate\Support\Facades\DB;

class UsercarSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {

        $json = file_get_contents('database/data/user-cars.json');
        $data = json_decode($json);

        $user = User::where('old_user_id', 'old_user_id')->get();
        $car = Car::where('old_car_id', 'old_car_id')->get();

        foreach ($data as $obj) {
            Usercar::create(array(
                'user_id' => $user->id,
                'car_id' => $car->id,
...
```

Comment: I didn't understand really, but the problem is the `id` and I think in `'user_id' => $user->id`

Comment: And why you have `old_user_id` in new table ? it's better to have just `id`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `get()` method returns a collection of models. If you need a single object, you should be using the `first()` method.

Also the `where()` should look something like:

```php
->where($column, $value)
```

Looks like you are passing the column name twice which would probably return an empty collection.